# Unix/Bash: Uniq on a cell

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a tab-separated fileA where the 12th column (starting from 1) contain several comma separated identifiers. Some of them in the same row, however, can occur more than once:

```
GO:0042302, GO:0042302, GO:0042302
GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281, GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281
....
....
```

(some with a white-space after the comma, some where it is not).

I would like to only get the unique identifiers and remove the multiples for each row in the 12th column:

```
GO:0042302
GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281
....
....
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
for row in `fileA`
do
    cut -f12 $row | sed "s/,/\n/" | sort | uniq | paste fileA - | \
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"}{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $13}'
done > out
```

The idea was to go over each row at a time, cut out the 12th column, replace all commas with newlines and then sort and take uniq to get rid of duplicates, paste it back and print the columns in the right order, skipping the original identifier column.

However, this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify "does not seem to work"?  What is it doing instead of what you want?

Comment: What results are you getting after the `sed` command? Delete from `sort` to the end of the line and just pipe it to `less` (or just look at the results in your console if it's limited enough).

Comment: `sort | uniq` can be replaced with `sort -u`

Comment: Did you mean `for row in \`cat fileA\``? Since `cut` and `sed` and etc are all working on the WHOLE file (ALL lines), how are you planning on matching the lines back up so you can `paste` it back together? I don't think you are using the right tools for the job right now... Either perl or awk would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then with awk:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { delete b; n = split($12, a, /, */); $12 = ""; for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { if(!(a[i] in b)) { b[a[i]]; $12 = $12 a[i] "," } } sub(/,$/, "", $12); print }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }           # output FS same as input FS
{
  delete b                   # clear dirty table from last pass

  n = split($12, a, /, */)   # split 12th field into tokens,
  $12 = ""                   # then clear it out for reassembly

  for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {  # wade through those tokens
    if(!(a[i] in b)) {       # those that haven't been seen yet:
      b[a[i]]                # remember that they were seen
      $12 = $12 a[i] ","     # append to result
    }
  }
  sub(/,$/, "", $12)         # remove trailing comma from resulting field

  print                      # print the transformed line
}
```

The `delete b;` has been POSIX-conforming for only a short while, so if you're working with an old, old awk and it fails for you, see @MarkReed's comment for another way that ancient awks should accept.

Comment: Actually, even though it's not part of the POSIX spec, `delete` *arrayvar* works in most implementations, including BSD; it's not a GNU extension.  However, if you want to be POSIX-compliant, you can also just split an empty string into the array to clear it: `split("",b,":");`

Comment: That's good to know and a nice (if ugly) trick. I'll keep it in mind for when I have to deal with ancient awks. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, according to the GNU awk manual, `delete array` has been accepted into POSIX in 2012, so it's canonical now. That's good.

Comment: alternate loop:  `for (i=0; ++i<=n; ) if (!b[a[i]]++) r=r a[i] ","`
`

Comment: You could reduce this by removing variable `r` and just setting `$12=""` then adding each element directly to $12

Comment: That's not a bad idea, so I put it in.

Comment: How would you do this without sorting?

Comment: It is without sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, and because I personally prefer Perl over Awk for this sort of thing, here's a Perl one-liner solution:

```
perl -F'\t' -le '%u=();@k=split/,/,$F[11];@u{@k}=@k;$F[11]=join",",sort
        keys%u;print join"\t",@F'
```

Explanation:

```
-F'\t'  Loop over input lines, splitting each one into fields at tabs
-l      automatically remove newlines from input and append on output
-e      get code to execute from the next argument instead of standard input

%u = ();                 # clear out the hash variable %u
@k = split /,/, $F[11];  # Split 12th field (1st is 0) on comma into array @k               
@u{@k} = @k;             # Copy the contents of @k into @u as key/value pairs
```

Because hash keys are unique, that last step means that the keys of `%u` are now a deduplicated copy of `@k`.

```
$F[11] = join ",", sort keys %u; # replace the 12th field with the sorted unique list
print join "\t", @F;             # and print out the modified line
```

Comment: Add lexical `sort` before `keys %u`. The OP says: _then sort and take uniq to get rid of duplicates_.

Comment: Thanks @jm666.  Missed that part of the requirement.

Comment: This perl one-liner does not seem to work. I get "Bad name after F' at perltest.pl line 3".

Comment: Are you trying to run the explanation as code?  `-F` is a command line option, not part of the program.  You run the first version from the shell, not the second one as a script.

Answer (score 1):

Using field 2 instead of field 12:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    split($2,f,/ *, */)
    $2 = ""
    delete seen
    for (i=1;i in f;i++) {
        if ( !seen[f[i]]++ ) {
            $2 = $2 (i>1?",":"") f[i]
        }
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
a,a,a   GO:0042302, GO:0042302, GO:0042302      b,b,b
c,c,c   GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281, GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281      d,d,d

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,a,a   GO:0042302      b,b,b
c,c,c   GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281        d,d,d
```

If your awk doesn't support `delete seen` you can use `split("",seen)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this awk:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{
      delete seen;
      split($12, a, /[,; ]+/);
      for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) {
         if (!(a[i] in seen)) {
            seen[a[i]];
            s=sprintf("%s%s,", s, a[i])
         }
      }
$12=s} 1' file
GO:0042302,
GO:0042302,GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281,
```

Comment: This will break if a token is seen in different lines because you don't clear the `seen` array. Other than that, it's pretty much what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In your example data, the comma followed by a space is the delimiter of the 12th field.  Every subfield after that is merely a repeat of the first field.  The subfields appear to already be in sorted order.

```
GO:0042302, GO:0042302, GO:0042302
            ^^^dup1^^^  ^^^dup2^^^
GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281, GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^dup1^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Based on that, you could simply keep the first of the subfields and toss the rest:

```
awk -F"\t" '{sub(/, .*/, "", $12)} 1' fileA
```

If instead, you can have different sets of repeated subfields, where keys are not sorted like this:

```
GO:0042302, GO:0042302, GO:0042302, GO:0062122,GO:0055000, GO:0055001, GO:0062122,GO:0055000
GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281, GO:0005525, GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0006281
```

If you were stuck with a default MacOS awk you could introduce a sort/uniq functions in an awk executable script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="\t"}

{
    c = uniq(a, split($12, a, /, |,/))
    sort(a, c)
    s = a[1]
    for(i=2; i<=c; i++) { s = s "," a[i] }
    $2 = s
}

47  # print out the modified line

    # take an indexed arr as from split and de-dup it
function uniq(arr, len,      i, uarr) {
    for(i=len; i>=1; i--) { uarr[arr[i]] }
    delete arr
    for(k in uarr) { arr[++i] = k }
    return( i )
}

    # slightly modified from
    # http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#AWK
function sort(arr, len,      haschanged, tmp, i)
{
    haschanged = 1
    while( haschanged==1 ) {
        haschanged = 0

        for(i=1; i<=(len-1); i++) {
            if( arr[i] > arr[i+1] ) {
                tmp = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
                arr[i + 1] = tmp
                haschanged = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you had GNU-awk, I think you could swap out the `sort(a, c)` call with `asort(a)`, and drop the bubble-sort local function completely.

I get the following for the 12th field:

```
GO:0042302,GO:0055000,GO:0055001,GO:0062122
GO:0004386,GO:0005524,GO:0005525,GO:0006281
```